# Rails Check if Controller Index Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to check if there exists an index action for a controller? Something like:

```
Controller.indexActionExists?
```

I have seen posts to check if specific routes exist, but those methods aren't working for me, since some of my index actions aren't associated with routes.

Comment: why would you want to do this...?

Comment: making a page of indices with link_to's, but I keep getting errors from controllers whose indices aren't implemented. If I could catch a bad link_to that would work too, but it would have to be better than just checking if the url exists, since the problem is putting out the url in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

The `action_methods` method is going to be the most expedient tool in this case, returning a `Set` of method names. Give the following code a shot:

```
# Get a set of method names belonging to a controller called 'MyController'

methods = MyController.action_methods

if methods.include? "index"
  puts "MyController has an index method"
else
  puts "MyController lacks an index method"
end
```